# MVC just certain model updated before POST method reached?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dilemma: in an MVC application I am fiddling with there is an ordering form where you list articles with certain parameters, for example name, price and quantity.

Price used to be presented as a plain text value, but now it should be editable. I simply switched over to a textbox to display the price and it work fine, in the exact manner as it was done for quantity (which has been editable all along).

The form action is set to the method CAtrticles, but when the method is hit the value for quality is already updated in the passed viewmodel, but price is not? It retains the original value that is set in the textbox when it is created?

```
public ActionResult CArticles(OCAViewModel vm)
```

I cant figure out for the world WHERE the quantity is set to the new value as set in the textbox and why price is not?

Comment: Please also show the code in your View for the textbox.

Comment: did you set the correct "name" attribute for your textbox? Are there any other controls on the page (e.g. hidden field) with the same "name"?

Comment: Therw was a hidden field for the same property! I removed it and now it works, the value is captured. Thanks @ADyson

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by @ADyson, the error lied in that there was a HiddenField with the same value in the .cshtml page. Once removed, the Model updates as expected.